# Node js download files to server into specific folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, server, download

The current code downloads the file to the root of the folder which is the dest , How can we specify the folders for it to be downloaded. For example I have folder which is Project/Server/files/ .

## Code

var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

```
                request.get(url)
                    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
                    .on('close', callback);

            };

            final_list.forEach(function (str) {
                var filename = str.split('/').pop();

                console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

                download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
            });
```

Comment: change `filename` to suit your needs..

Comment: file name has nothing to do with it

Comment: The problem is to speficify the download folder

Comment: `filename` is `dest`, it has everything to do with it. This is server to server code, dont confuse it for code to download to a users browser, and if true you cant define where files are downloaded to, else would be a security risk.

Comment: can you post your answer so i can check and then upvote , thanks

Comment: I wanted to download the file to for example Project/Server/files/  , the current code downloads the file to the root which is in Project

Comment: add the path to filename i.e `download(str, './Server/files/' + filename, ...`

Comment: Thanks for the idea , post it as an answer sir so i can upvote. so you will get points for it , thanks